# adding a new conditional column in pandas based off different indexes

Tags: python, excel, pandas

[image]

hello! I am trying to add a new column in my pandas Dataframe based off of conditional formatting of an index other than the adjacent cell. I am trying to replicate the "consecutive match" column shown in my image. the excel conditional formula I used to create this column is shown as well!
thank so much!

Comment: Please do not include images of data. Always put your data in text format, so it can be copy/pasted, or better still post python code that creates your dataframe. This way people will actually be able to use the data to try and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please take the time to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15239951)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
sr = df["muni_name"]
df["consecutive_match"] = sr.groupby(sr.ne(sr.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1
```

```py
>>> df
             muni_name  consecutive_match
0        East Escambia                  1
1              Brewton                  1
2        East Escambia                  1
3        East Escambia                  2
4        East Escambia                  3
5        East Escambia                  4
6               Atmore                  1
7              Brewton                  1
8   McCullough-Huxford                  1
9               Atmore                  1
10            Flomaton                  1
11            Flomaton                  2
12            Flomaton                  3
```